# Codeigniter Active Record HAVING / WHERE db.field = db.field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Can someone tell me, if this is possible with active record - and how??

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.fi_id', 'left');
$this->db->having('table1.second_id','table2.fi_second_id', false);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The problem ist, that 'table2.fi_second_id' is always treated as a **string** - not as a **database field**. Tried this with 'where' also - it's the same problem.

Thx

Comment: why not use a simple query using `$this->db->query()`, its more flexible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that you want the following:

```
$this->db->having('table1.second_id = table2.fi_second_id',false);
```

You may or may not apply the `false` parameter if you don't need escaped SQL queries.